# Make underlined text to stretch 100%

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following for displaying text on the screen:

```
<TextView
        android:text="@string/today_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

  // XML
  <string name="today_label"><u>Today</u></string>
```

### Actual Result

[image: Actual]

### Expected Result

[image: Expected]

Comment: android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: @Daryl `fill` deprecated .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya is correct and still doesn't work if used

Comment: ok thanks @IntelliJAmiya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a `View` for that:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#cccccc" />
```

In e.g. `LinearLayout`. Something like here: [Android underline whole textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786917/android-underline-whole-textview)

If you underline the text like that:

```
<string name="today_label"><u>Today</u></string>
```

You will always underline only a text.